# How to change parent attribute in subclass python

Tags: python, oop, namespaces, subclassing

I have the following class

```
class Foo():
    data = "abc"
```

And i subclass it

```
class Bar(Foo):
    data +="def"
```

I am trying to edit a parent class attribute in subclass. I want my parent class to have some string, and my subclass should add some extra data to that string. How it should be done in Python? Am i wrong by design?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You ask two questions:

> > > How it should be done in Python?

```
class Bar(Foo):
    data = Foo.data + "def"
```

> > > Am i wrong by design?

I generally don't use class variables in Python. A more typical paradigm is to initialize an instance variable:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...  data = "abc"
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(Bar, self).__init__()
...         self.data += "def"
... 
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.data
'abcdef'
>>>
```

Comment: Couldn't edit, because such a small change, but be sure to add a closing quote.

Comment: Thank you! Btw is it a good practice to store data in classes this way?

Answer (score 7):

You can initialize the state of the Foo class from the Bar class and then append to the data like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = "abc"

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.data += "def"
```

When you instantiate an instance of Bar, the value of data that results is:

```
abcdef
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to class variables of Foo from Bar's namespace via regular attribute access:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    data = Foo.data + 'def'
```

I don't know if it's a good practice, but there's no reason for it to be bad.